# How to save a csv file to folder

Tags: apex, csv, folder

I needed to do generate a csv file and save it to salesforce folder every day at 08:00 AM.

So i did the generating a csv file every day at 08:00 AM with:

```apex
public class TrucksExport implements Schedulable {
    public void execute (SchedulableContext ctx) {
        String csv = 'Id,Truck Pictures,Fuel Tank Size,Status,Price,TruckID,Name\n';
        for ( List<Truck__c> trucks : [ Select Status__c, Fuel_Tank_Size__c, Id, Name, Price__c, State__City__s, State__PostalCode__s, State__c, TruckId__c, Truck_Pictures__c, Type__c FROM Truck__c ] ) {
            for ( Truck__c truck : trucks ) {
                csv += truck.id + ','+ truck.Truck_Pictures__c + ','+ truck.Fuel_Tank_Size__c + ','+ truck.Status__c + ',' + truck.Price__c + ','+ truck.TruckId__c + ',' + truck.name.escapeCsv() + '\n';
            }
        }
        ContentVersion file = new ContentVersion(
            title = 'TrucksWithPics4.csv',
            versionData = Blob.valueOf( csv ),
            pathOnClient = '/Trucks.csv'
        );
        insert file;
    }
}
```

And it generates a csv file in files, but i dont know how to generate that csv file to a designated folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you should query the ContentDocumentId from your content version.

ContentVersion conVer = [SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = :file.Id LIMIT 1];

2. Query the contentworkspace

ContentWorkspace ws = [SELECT Id, RootContentFolderId FROM ContentWorkspace WHERE Name = 'folderName' LIMIT 1];

3. create a [contentDocumentlink](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm)

   ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink();
   cdl.ContentDocumentId = conVer.ContentDocumentId;
   cdl.ShareType = 'I';
   cdl.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
   cdl.LinkedEntityId = ws.Id;
   insert cdl;

PS: you can also create a [ContentWorkspaceDoc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentworkspacedoc.htm) . Click on the hyperlink for more info.

Comment: If i am being honest, i am a bit lost.  

ContentVersion is where i query for the csv file?

ContentWorkspace is for the destination folder?

ContentDocumentLink is the part where i put the csv file in the folder?

I am sorry, i am still learning this stuff.

Comment: Query on contentversion will give you the id of the document. 
Contentworkspace is the library(folder).
ContentDocumentlink represents the link between a Salesforce CRM Content document, Salesforce file, or ContentNote and where it's shared.